# Why does Windows 7 keep reverting to previous state?

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-restore

I'm on Windows 7 Home Premium 32-bit with SP1. I have auto-update turned on and have all the latest Windows updates AFAIK.

Every now and then, my system reverts itself to a previous state, including:

- wallpaper
- taskbar items
- start menu items
- programs listed in the "Programs and Features" control panel (e.g. successfully uninstalled programs reappear)
- default browser (reverts from Chrome to Firefox)
- contents of long-standing directories (the contents of recently created directories are correct)

I don't care about the cosmetic stuff like wallpaper, but obviously the changes to the file system are a worry.

I've Googled for possible causes, but found nothing useful. There are a number of restore points listed in the System control panel, but I haven't chosen to go back to any of them.

I'm on the verge of reinstalling Windows unless anyone has an idea why this is happening?

Also, I have admin rights on this machine; the other family members do not. AFAIK, I'm the only user affected.

Comment: This does sound a lot like system restore, are you 100% certain you are the only user with the power to revert changes?  Do you ever leave the machine unlocked for other people to use?

Comment: Have you looked through the Event Logs for signs yet?

Comment: I would suspect (and this is only a guess) that, during an update or similar, something goes wrong and so the OS restores itself to a last known working set up... which is without your changes etc. You could see if there is any indication of failing updates to rule this out easily enough.